# File in documents Directory after deletion

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdocumentdirectory

I created an sqlite file[or any file] in documents directory in ios device.If i removed the app (delete) from the device this file stays or get removed?

Comment: PS: to see for myself i dont have a device with me right now

Comment: if u remove your app. the it will be removed "_

Comment: this file delete automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents directory allows you to store files and subdirectories your app creates or may need, for example a database.

Your application works in a sandbox environment. When you delete the application in simulator or device, the directory that was created by application **is deleted** and so do the files residing in it.

When you reset your simulator you can find the deleted files in the trash.

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox of an application deletes automatically when you delete the app. It happens in both your device and in iOS simulator.