# Documents directory being kept after delete and reinstall of iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

I know that when an iOS app is deleted the corresponding documents directory should also be deleted as per [this article's explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912061/file-in-documents-directory-after-deletion) but I am running iOS version 7.0.3 and when I delete one of our apps from my device, and then immediately re-install it from the AppStore (on the device), it is keeping the contents of the old documents directory.

After deleting the app, rebooting the device, and reinstalling the app, the old contents of the documents directory are gone.

Even deleting the app and waiting 15 minutes doesn't help. It has to be rebooted.

I've confirmed this on 2 different iPhone 5s.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be going on here?

Also, we mark the contents we create in the documents directory so that they are not backed up to iCloud so I don't think iCloud is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds more like a user-level question than a programming question.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem effecting our users but I need to know if it is a bug in the current version of iOS or something I am missing when I create the app?

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure that it isn't automatically synching with iCloud.  There's a chance that the fresh install of the app is fetching your old files from iCloud.  You can turn this off in Settings. Good luck!