# Flutter iOS app: images picked and stored offline using file_picker are missing after app update - how can I fix this issue?

Tags: ios, flutter, image, dart

I have an flutter iOS application that allows the user to pick images from device gallery while device internet is off.  Then I store the respective image path in SQFLight Db  and Once the user got internet I'll send the images to server

Now the problem is when I pick image and stored the path in DB then I updated the New version app from testflight the saved images are missing

I'm using file_picker: ^5.2.5 to pick images

Any Help on this ?

Comment: Maybe you use temporary path to store in DB. Well becuz it is temporary, it will change every time you update app... check out this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67859341/flutter-ios-when-apps-update-recompile-stored-image-is-missing?rq=2

Comment: I have stored image file name with extension alone while show the image in the UI I'll fetch the current document directory dynamically  and merge the filename with directory at the time of image rendering this works for me!!!